# Repository unit-testing on a library project

Tags: maven, unit-testing, spring-boot

I am working on a multi module project using Spring Boot. I want to write some unit tests to check my repository, services, etc. 
The repositories codes is written on a common project which is used on other projects. This project doesn't contain any starter app. It's just composed of entities, repositories and services.

I saw this topic ([How to test Maven module project with Spring Boot](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/37615914/how-to-test-maven-module-project-with-spring-boot)) about a similar issue but I don't manage to succeed to implement it for testing my repository.

The exception "NoSuchBeanDefinitionException" is raised for the EntityARepository (see the code below) when I launch the test : I understand that the tests can access to bean that I have created on the src/main/java folder. How can I resolve this ?

On the test folder (test/java) of this maven project, I create three files on several packages :

```
package com.domain.test
@SpringBootApplication()
public class ProjectCommonsTestApplication {
    public static void main(String[] args) {
        SpringApplication.run(ProjectCommonsTestApplication.class, args);
    }
}
```

```
package com.domain.test.repository

@RunWith(SpringRunner.class)
@DataJpaTest
public class EntityARepositoryTest {

    @Autowired
    private TestEntityManager entityManager;

    @Autowired
    private EntityARepository entityARepository;

    @Test
    public void someUnitTest(){
        //given
        //when
        //then
    }
}
```

And the application.yml file, on the folder test/resources

```
spring:
  application:
    name: Spring Boot - TEST instance
  datasource:
    type: com.zaxxer.hikari.HikariDataSource
    url: "jdbc:h2:mem:test-api;INIT=CREATE SCHEMA IF NOT EXISTS dbo\\;CREATE SCHEMA IF NOT EXISTS definitions;DATABASE_TO_UPPER=false;DB_CLOSE_DELAY=-1;DB_CLOSE_ON_EXIT=false;MODE=MSSQLServer"
    name:
    password:
    username:
    initialization-mode: never
    hikari:
      schema: dbo
  jpa:
    database: H2
    database-platform: org.hibernate.dialect.H2Dialect
    show-sql: true
    hibernate:
      ddl-auto: create-drop
  test:
    database:
      replace: none
```

Have you an idea of what is wrong on my code ? The repository is well anotated and written on src/main/java on a sub-package : com.domain.repository

Thanks in advance.

EDIT : 
The trace of the error :

```
org.springframework.beans.factory.UnsatisfiedDependencyException: Error creating bean with name 'com.domain.test.repository.EntityARepository': Unsatisfied dependency expressed through field 'entityARepository'; nested exception is org.springframework.beans.factory.NoSuchBeanDefinitionException: No qualifying bean of type 'com.domain.repository.EntityARepository' available: expected at least 1 bean which qualifies as autowire candidate. Dependency annotations: {@org.springframework.beans.factory.annotation.Autowired(required=true)}
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.annotation.AutowiredAnnotationBeanPostProcessor$AutowiredFieldElement.inject(AutowiredAnnotationBeanPostProcessor.java:587) ~[spring-beans-5.0.6.RELEASE.jar:5.0.6.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.annotation.InjectionMetadata.inject(InjectionMetadata.java:91) ~[spring-beans-5.0.6.RELEASE.jar:5.0.6.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.annotation.AutowiredAnnotationBeanPostProcessor.postProcessPropertyValues(AutowiredAnnotationBeanPostProcessor.java:373) ~[spring-beans-5.0.6.RELEASE.jar:5.0.6.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.populateBean(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:1348) ~[spring-beans-5.0.6.RELEASE.jar:5.0.6.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.autowireBeanProperties(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:399) ~[spring-beans-5.0.6.RELEASE.jar:5.0.6.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.test.context.support.DependencyInjectionTestExecutionListener.injectDependencies(DependencyInjectionTestExecutionListener.java:118) ~[spring-test-5.0.6.RELEASE.jar:5.0.6.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.test.context.support.DependencyInjectionTestExecutionListener.prepareTestInstance(DependencyInjectionTestExecutionListener.java:83) ~[spring-test-5.0.6.RELEASE.jar:5.0.6.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.boot.test.autoconfigure.SpringBootDependencyInjectionTestExecutionListener.prepareTestInstance(SpringBootDependencyInjectionTestExecutionListener.java:44) ~[spring-boot-test-autoconfigure-2.0.2.RELEASE.jar:2.0.2.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.test.context.TestContextManager.prepareTestInstance(TestContextManager.java:246) ~[spring-test-5.0.6.RELEASE.jar:5.0.6.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.test.context.junit4.SpringJUnit4ClassRunner.createTest(SpringJUnit4ClassRunner.java:227) [spring-test-5.0.6.RELEASE.jar:5.0.6.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.test.context.junit4.SpringJUnit4ClassRunner$1.runReflectiveCall(SpringJUnit4ClassRunner.java:289) [spring-test-5.0.6.RELEASE.jar:5.0.6.RELEASE]
    at org.junit.internal.runners.model.ReflectiveCallable.run(ReflectiveCallable.java:12) [junit-4.12.jar:4.12]
    at org.springframework.test.context.junit4.SpringJUnit4ClassRunner.methodBlock(SpringJUnit4ClassRunner.java:291) [spring-test-5.0.6.RELEASE.jar:5.0.6.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.test.context.junit4.SpringJUnit4ClassRunner.runChild(SpringJUnit4ClassRunner.java:246) [spring-test-5.0.6.RELEASE.jar:5.0.6.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.test.context.junit4.SpringJUnit4ClassRunner.runChild(SpringJUnit4ClassRunner.java:97) [spring-test-5.0.6.RELEASE.jar:5.0.6.RELEASE]
    at org.junit.runners.ParentRunner$3.run(ParentRunner.java:290) [junit-4.12.jar:4.12]
    at org.junit.runners.ParentRunner$1.schedule(ParentRunner.java:71) [junit-4.12.jar:4.12]
    at org.junit.runners.ParentRunner.runChildren(ParentRunner.java:288) [junit-4.12.jar:4.12]
    at org.junit.runners.ParentRunner.access$000(ParentRunner.java:58) [junit-4.12.jar:4.12]
    at org.junit.runners.ParentRunner$2.evaluate(ParentRunner.java:268) [junit-4.12.jar:4.12]
    at org.springframework.test.context.junit4.statements.RunBeforeTestClassCallbacks.evaluate(RunBeforeTestClassCallbacks.java:61) [spring-test-5.0.6.RELEASE.jar:5.0.6.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.test.context.junit4.statements.RunAfterTestClassCallbacks.evaluate(RunAfterTestClassCallbacks.java:70) [spring-test-5.0.6.RELEASE.jar:5.0.6.RELEASE]
    at org.junit.runners.ParentRunner.run(ParentRunner.java:363) [junit-4.12.jar:4.12]
    at org.springframework.test.context.junit4.SpringJUnit4ClassRunner.run(SpringJUnit4ClassRunner.java:190) [spring-test-5.0.6.RELEASE.jar:5.0.6.RELEASE]
    at org.junit.runner.JUnitCore.run(JUnitCore.java:137) [junit-4.12.jar:4.12]
    at com.intellij.junit4.JUnit4IdeaTestRunner.startRunnerWithArgs(JUnit4IdeaTestRunner.java:68) [junit-rt.jar:na]
    at com.intellij.rt.execution.junit.IdeaTestRunner$Repeater.startRunnerWithArgs(IdeaTestRunner.java:47) [junit-rt.jar:na]
    at com.intellij.rt.execution.junit.JUnitStarter.prepareStreamsAndStart(JUnitStarter.java:242) [junit-rt.jar:na]
    at com.intellij.rt.execution.junit.JUnitStarter.main(JUnitStarter.java:70) [junit-rt.jar:na]
Caused by: org.springframework.beans.factory.NoSuchBeanDefinitionException: No qualifying bean of type 'com.domain.repositoryEntityARepository' available: expected at least 1 bean which qualifies as autowire candidate. Dependency annotations: {@org.springframework.beans.factory.annotation.Autowired(required=true)}
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.DefaultListableBeanFactory.raiseNoMatchingBeanFound(DefaultListableBeanFactory.java:1509) ~[spring-beans-5.0.6.RELEASE.jar:5.0.6.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.DefaultListableBeanFactory.doResolveDependency(DefaultListableBeanFactory.java:1104) ~[spring-beans-5.0.6.RELEASE.jar:5.0.6.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.DefaultListableBeanFactory.resolveDependency(DefaultListableBeanFactory.java:1065) ~[spring-beans-5.0.6.RELEASE.jar:5.0.6.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.annotation.AutowiredAnnotationBeanPostProcessor$AutowiredFieldElement.inject(AutowiredAnnotationBeanPostProcessor.java:584) ~[spring-beans-5.0.6.RELEASE.jar:5.0.6.RELEASE]
    ... 28 common frames omitted
```

EDIT 2 : 
When I add @ContextConfiguration with the right class to be autowired, the error changes :

```
package com.domain.test.repository

@RunWith(SpringRunner.class)
@ContextConfiguration(classes = EntityARepository.class)
@DataJpaTest
public class EntityARepositoryTest {

    @Autowired
    private TestEntityManager entityManager;

    @Autowired
    private EntityARepository entityARepository;

    @Test
    public void someUnitTest(){
        //given
        //when
        //then
    }
}
```

```
java.lang.IllegalStateException: Unable to retrieve @EnableAutoConfiguration base packages
    at org.springframework.boot.autoconfigure.AutoConfigurationPackages.get(AutoConfigurationPackages.java:76) ~[spring-boot-autoconfigure-2.0.2.RELEASE.jar:2.0.2.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.boot.autoconfigure.data.AbstractRepositoryConfigurationSourceSupport.getBasePackages(AbstractRepositoryConfigurationSourceSupport.java:79) ~[spring-boot-autoconfigure-2.0.2.RELEASE.jar:2.0.2.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.boot.autoconfigure.data.AbstractRepositoryConfigurationSourceSupport$1.getBasePackages(AbstractRepositoryConfigurationSourceSupport.java:73) ~[spring-boot-autoconfigure-2.0.2.RELEASE.jar:2.0.2.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.data.repository.config.RepositoryConfigurationSourceSupport.lambda$getCandidates$2(RepositoryConfigurationSourceSupport.java:77) ~[spring-data-commons-2.0.7.RELEASE.jar:2.0.7.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.data.util.LazyStreamable.stream(LazyStreamable.java:50) ~[spring-data-commons-2.0.7.RELEASE.jar:2.0.7.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.data.util.LazyStreamable.iterator(LazyStreamable.java:41) ~[spring-data-commons-2.0.7.RELEASE.jar:2.0.7.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.data.repository.config.RepositoryConfigurationExtensionSupport.getRepositoryConfigurations(RepositoryConfigurationExtensionSupport.java:87) ~[spring-data-commons-2.0.7.RELEASE.jar:2.0.7.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.data.repository.config.RepositoryConfigurationDelegate.registerRepositoriesIn(RepositoryConfigurationDelegate.java:121) ~[spring-data-commons-2.0.7.RELEASE.jar:2.0.7.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.boot.autoconfigure.data.AbstractRepositoryConfigurationSourceSupport.registerBeanDefinitions(AbstractRepositoryConfigurationSourceSupport.java:60) ~[spring-boot-autoconfigure-2.0.2.RELEASE.jar:2.0.2.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.context.annotation.ConfigurationClassBeanDefinitionReader.lambda$loadBeanDefinitionsFromRegistrars$1(ConfigurationClassBeanDefinitionReader.java:358) ~[spring-context-5.0.6.RELEASE.jar:5.0.6.RELEASE]
    at java.util.LinkedHashMap.forEach(LinkedHashMap.java:676) ~[na:1.8.0_91-3-redhat]
    at org.springframework.context.annotation.ConfigurationClassBeanDefinitionReader.loadBeanDefinitionsFromRegistrars(ConfigurationClassBeanDefinitionReader.java:357) ~[spring-context-5.0.6.RELEASE.jar:5.0.6.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.context.annotation.ConfigurationClassBeanDefinitionReader.loadBeanDefinitionsForConfigurationClass(ConfigurationClassBeanDefinitionReader.java:145) ~[spring-context-5.0.6.RELEASE.jar:5.0.6.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.context.annotation.ConfigurationClassBeanDefinitionReader.loadBeanDefinitions(ConfigurationClassBeanDefinitionReader.java:117) ~[spring-context-5.0.6.RELEASE.jar:5.0.6.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.context.annotation.ConfigurationClassPostProcessor.processConfigBeanDefinitions(ConfigurationClassPostProcessor.java:328) ~[spring-context-5.0.6.RELEASE.jar:5.0.6.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.context.annotation.ConfigurationClassPostProcessor.postProcessBeanDefinitionRegistry(ConfigurationClassPostProcessor.java:233) ~[spring-context-5.0.6.RELEASE.jar:5.0.6.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.context.support.PostProcessorRegistrationDelegate.invokeBeanDefinitionRegistryPostProcessors(PostProcessorRegistrationDelegate.java:273) ~[spring-context-5.0.6.RELEASE.jar:5.0.6.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.context.support.PostProcessorRegistrationDelegate.invokeBeanFactoryPostProcessors(PostProcessorRegistrationDelegate.java:93) ~[spring-context-5.0.6.RELEASE.jar:5.0.6.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.context.support.AbstractApplicationContext.invokeBeanFactoryPostProcessors(AbstractApplicationContext.java:694) ~[spring-context-5.0.6.RELEASE.jar:5.0.6.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.context.support.AbstractApplicationContext.refresh(AbstractApplicationContext.java:532) ~[spring-context-5.0.6.RELEASE.jar:5.0.6.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.boot.SpringApplication.refresh(SpringApplication.java:759) ~[spring-boot-2.0.2.RELEASE.jar:2.0.2.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.boot.SpringApplication.refreshContext(SpringApplication.java:395) ~[spring-boot-2.0.2.RELEASE.jar:2.0.2.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.boot.SpringApplication.run(SpringApplication.java:327) ~[spring-boot-2.0.2.RELEASE.jar:2.0.2.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.boot.test.context.SpringBootContextLoader.loadContext(SpringBootContextLoader.java:139) [spring-boot-test-2.0.2.RELEASE.jar:2.0.2.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.test.context.cache.DefaultCacheAwareContextLoaderDelegate.loadContextInternal(DefaultCacheAwareContextLoaderDelegate.java:99) [spring-test-5.0.6.RELEASE.jar:5.0.6.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.test.context.cache.DefaultCacheAwareContextLoaderDelegate.loadContext(DefaultCacheAwareContextLoaderDelegate.java:117) [spring-test-5.0.6.RELEASE.jar:5.0.6.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.test.context.support.DefaultTestContext.getApplicationContext(DefaultTestContext.java:108) [spring-test-5.0.6.RELEASE.jar:5.0.6.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.boot.test.autoconfigure.SpringBootDependencyInjectionTestExecutionListener.outputConditionEvaluationReport(SpringBootDependencyInjectionTestExecutionListener.java:54) [spring-boot-test-autoconfigure-2.0.2.RELEASE.jar:2.0.2.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.boot.test.autoconfigure.SpringBootDependencyInjectionTestExecutionListener.prepareTestInstance(SpringBootDependencyInjectionTestExecutionListener.java:47) [spring-boot-test-autoconfigure-2.0.2.RELEASE.jar:2.0.2.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.test.context.TestContextManager.prepareTestInstance(TestContextManager.java:246) [spring-test-5.0.6.RELEASE.jar:5.0.6.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.test.context.junit4.SpringJUnit4ClassRunner.createTest(SpringJUnit4ClassRunner.java:227) [spring-test-5.0.6.RELEASE.jar:5.0.6.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.test.context.junit4.SpringJUnit4ClassRunner$1.runReflectiveCall(SpringJUnit4ClassRunner.java:289) [spring-test-5.0.6.RELEASE.jar:5.0.6.RELEASE]
    at org.junit.internal.runners.model.ReflectiveCallable.run(ReflectiveCallable.java:12) [junit-4.12.jar:4.12]
    at org.springframework.test.context.junit4.SpringJUnit4ClassRunner.methodBlock(SpringJUnit4ClassRunner.java:291) [spring-test-5.0.6.RELEASE.jar:5.0.6.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.test.context.junit4.SpringJUnit4ClassRunner.runChild(SpringJUnit4ClassRunner.java:246) [spring-test-5.0.6.RELEASE.jar:5.0.6.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.test.context.junit4.SpringJUnit4ClassRunner.runChild(SpringJUnit4ClassRunner.java:97) [spring-test-5.0.6.RELEASE.jar:5.0.6.RELEASE]
    at org.junit.runners.ParentRunner$3.run(ParentRunner.java:290) [junit-4.12.jar:4.12]
    at org.junit.runners.ParentRunner$1.schedule(ParentRunner.java:71) [junit-4.12.jar:4.12]
    at org.junit.runners.ParentRunner.runChildren(ParentRunner.java:288) [junit-4.12.jar:4.12]
    at org.junit.runners.ParentRunner.access$000(ParentRunner.java:58) [junit-4.12.jar:4.12]
    at org.junit.runners.ParentRunner$2.evaluate(ParentRunner.java:268) [junit-4.12.jar:4.12]
    at org.springframework.test.context.junit4.statements.RunBeforeTestClassCallbacks.evaluate(RunBeforeTestClassCallbacks.java:61) [spring-test-5.0.6.RELEASE.jar:5.0.6.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.test.context.junit4.statements.RunAfterTestClassCallbacks.evaluate(RunAfterTestClassCallbacks.java:70) [spring-test-5.0.6.RELEASE.jar:5.0.6.RELEASE]
    at org.junit.runners.ParentRunner.run(ParentRunner.java:363) [junit-4.12.jar:4.12]
    at org.springframework.test.context.junit4.SpringJUnit4ClassRunner.run(SpringJUnit4ClassRunner.java:190) [spring-test-5.0.6.RELEASE.jar:5.0.6.RELEASE]
    at org.junit.runner.JUnitCore.run(JUnitCore.java:137) [junit-4.12.jar:4.12]
    at com.intellij.junit4.JUnit4IdeaTestRunner.startRunnerWithArgs(JUnit4IdeaTestRunner.java:68) [junit-rt.jar:na]
    at com.intellij.rt.execution.junit.IdeaTestRunner$Repeater.startRunnerWithArgs(IdeaTestRunner.java:47) [junit-rt.jar:na]
    at com.intellij.rt.execution.junit.JUnitStarter.prepareStreamsAndStart(JUnitStarter.java:242) [junit-rt.jar:na]
    at com.intellij.rt.execution.junit.JUnitStarter.main(JUnitStarter.java:70) [junit-rt.jar:na]
```

Comment: Please give the full logging/error output cause there are many informations in there...

Comment: Done, I hope it will help

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I found a way to pass tests : no need to create a main function, only a @SpringBootConfiguration annotation on the ProjectCommonsTestApplication is needed.